# Query each table in a column in big query

Tags: sql, for-loop, google-bigquery

I need to "touch" all of our materialized views in a big query dataset periodically for a business use case. I was hoping to  be able to gather all of the table names in a SELECT statement, and then do a "FOR EACH" type of loop through each view name, but it seems like BQ will not allow this. Is there a better way to do what I am attempting below?

```
FOR record IN
  (SELECT CONCAT('project.dataset.', table_name) as full_name from `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
  WHERE table_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
DO
  SELECT 1 FROM record.full_name;
END FOR;
```

This query is supposed to run against the information schema to find all of the materialized views, and then loop through those and "select 1" from each table returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it seems like BQ will not allow this.

You can try it with [a dynamic sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate).

```sql
FOR record IN
  (SELECT CONCAT('project.dataset.', table_name) as full_name from `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
  WHERE table_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("SELECT 1 FROM `%s`;", record.full_name);
END FOR;
```